# How does compiler(GCC) deal with the access control for C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was wondering how does GCC deal with the control access (public, private, protected) of C++ code.

e.g.

```
class X
{   
public: 
    int a;    
    void funcA(){};  
private:
    int b;
    void funcB(){};
protected:
    int c;
    void funcC(){};
};
```

Of course, compiler will do access control checking at first.
However, my question is:

After generating the assembly code(.s file) or the object file(.o file), what's the different between the private variables/functions/objects and the public things in the assembly code and ELF files?

And how does the compiler set the control access for the code during compilation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing. Access modifiers are dealt with in the front-end only. Once the code is transformed into assembly language or object code, none of these things exist anymore.

Comment: Why do you think access control shows up in the compilation result to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access control is strictly a compile-time notion: if all of the accesses in the source code are okay, then the code compiles. There's nothing left to check at runtime, so access qualifiers make have no effect on the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the compiler will check access when compiling at first.

However, once the object file is generated, there is probably no check. In fact, you can do `#define private public` before you `#include` a header file, and then get access to private members.

It might be that some weird object file format or some set of compiler flags will try to make it harder to use the private members, but I expect all methods are almost as easy to work around as the `#define` trick, especially for accessing `protected` members as though they were `public` (because they need to be accessible to derived classes).

Comment: ````#define private public```` That is diabolical. I love it.

Comment: It’s obviously not usually a good idea, and it’s technically undefined behavior, but in practice it does work to access something’s private members.